# Is there any alternative for iterating through two different datatables which have 50K of records to iterate

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr2 in d.Rows)
    {
        if (dr2["Nme"].ToString().Equals(dr["CompanyName"].ToString()) && dr2["Executivename"].ToString().Equals(dr["Executivename"].ToString()))
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('This Data is alreay exist!');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide more details, you can do it with joins in sql

Comment: Yes. Don't. Whatever you want to do, don't pull 50K rows to the client to do whatever you want to do. Write a SQL query. What you posted is a simple JOIN and check for equality. Why do you need to pull all that to the client? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.CompanyName=table2.Nme and table1.ExecutiveName=table2.ExecutiveName`

Comment: Yes. But i have two diff DB.. So how can i join?
I want to check CompanyName and ExecutiveName are having matching records in both the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to do that in your database via sql. For example with a `JOIN` or `EXISTS` query. If that's not possible you can use this efficient and readable LINQ query:

```
var compData1 = dtt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new { CompanyName = r.Field<string>("CompanyName"),Executivename = r.Field<string>("Executivename")});
var compData2 = d.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new { CompanyName = r.Field<string>("Nme"), Executivename = r.Field<string>("Executivename") });

bool alreadyExists = compData1.Intersect(compData2).Any();

if(alreadyExists)
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('This Data is alreay exist!');", true);
```